# Drawing isosceles right triangle on unit circle for intuitive meaning of √2/2

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, visualization

Have you wondered about the meaning of $\sqrt{2}/2$ on the unit circle? Drawing a unit length line at $45^\circ$ from the origin, reflecting it on the $x$ axis and connecting the points where the lines intersect the unit circle creates an isosceles triangle. The hypotenuse of this triangle is of length $\sqrt{2}$ and it is halved by the $x$ axis. This half hypotenuse tangibly expresses $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, in other words, $\sin 45^\circ$.

What is the meaning of $\sqrt{3}/2$, how to take this idea further, and what are similar insights to be found?

An idea I tried is that a line can be drawn from the origin at 60˚, and a triangle can be made by reflecting this line on the $x$ axis. The resulting triangle, however, is not a right triangle. Nevertheless, it has a hypotenuse of length $\sqrt{3}$, so halving it results in $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, or $sin 60^\circ$.

[Visualisation of √2/2 on unit circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w5D0.jpg)

[Research for √3/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiJwm.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your reflection construction for an angle $\theta$ creates a *chord* "subtending" a central angle of $2\theta$; we might call this "the chord of $2\theta$". You've observed that the length of the chord is $2\sin\theta$. In other words, "the sine of an angle is *half the chord of twice the angle* [in a unit circle]". This is not unlike how sine was described historically. Indeed, it appears that the word "sine" followed a bit of a linguistic journey from the Sanskrit *jya-ardha* for "chord-half". (continued)

Comment: (continuing) Abbreviated to *jya*, the word was transcribed to Arabic as *jiba*, which in turn was abbreviated as *jb*, only to be misinterpreted as *jaib* ("bay") when converted to the Latin *sinus* by an unknown scholar. (See the ["Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics"](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/s/).) It's a fascinating story, but now we're stuck with trig functions *sine* and *cosine* whose names offer no insight into their geometric origins; compare this with *tangent* and *secant*, whose names directly reflect their geometry.

Comment: @Blue that's very interesting, I was surprised how this historical information can create curiosity and insight. Who knows, perhaps bay/cove relates more profoundly to the concept of sine. I didn't know that Sagitta was the versed sine, similar to an arrow, and chord is like the chord of a bow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting topic.

Given a starting line segment of length $1$, and a straightedge and a compass, we can use these to create many lengths.

Just as you described we can create $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$. Let's try to understand all the lengths we can create using these. We will call a number **constructible**, if it can be created using our apparatus. You can Search up [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number) is thats what you are interested in.

We can essentially create all positive integers easily. Then, by learning to create the right-angle, we can create all non-integer square-roots $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\dots$

You can try and explore this set of constructible numbers by yourself (call is $\mathcal{C}$), and come up with rules such as;

1. If $a, b\in\mathcal{C}$ then $a+b, a-b, ab, \frac{a}{b}, \sqrt{a^2+b^2},\sqrt{ab}$ are all in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Many thanks, your answer made me more interested, I started exploring constructible numbers! Why are √2 √3 and √5 non-integer, because their result is not an integer?